# Can I use custom matcher with toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, matcher

I need to check a URL that was passed to a method. I wrote a custom matcher for this but I don't know how to use it in `toHaveBeenCalledWith`.

How can I use my custom matcher in this situation?

E.g. in C# Moq I can do the following to match only even numbers:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Add(It.Is<int>(i => i % 2 == 0))).Returns(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not as elegant as what you're looking for, but you should be able to apply your custom matcher to `yourMockFunction.mock.calls[0][0]`.

```
expect(customMatcher(mockFunction.mock.calls[0][0])).toEqual(true)
```

If there are multiple arguments, you can read the next elements in `mockFunction.mock.calls[0]`. If you want to check multiple calls, they will be available in `mockFunction.mock.calls[1]`, `mockFunction.mock.calls[2]` and so on.